# AWS Sysprep script erase credentials from credential manager on Windows (with ansible and packer)

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, ansible, continuous-integration, amazon-ami

We've been using `Ansible` with `Packer` in order to create a windows `AMI` on `AWS`.
We have a need to create a windows credentials via the credentials manager so we could access a file sharing servers (yes, i know. It's legacy).

For some reasons the `win_credential` module don't create the credentials and no error message. The Yaml code we are using is below.

```
- name: Create a windows credential for qa.credifi.com
  win_credential:
    name: some.server.com
    type: domain_password
    username: administrator
    secret: XXXXXXXXXXXX
    state: present
    persistence: enterprise 
  become: yes
  become_method: runas
  become_user: administrator
  register: w_c
```

**UPDATE**
After some investigations i came to realize that the AWS `SysprepInstance.ps1`

What can be done to **NOT** erasing those credentials?

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: No, but after much try and error i know that i need to persist it to enterprise and the aws initialize script probably erase that